# Linux kernel source not configured - missing > version.h. when intall a driver

Tags: linux-kernel, driver

I'm trying to install a intel e1000 ethernet card driver on ubuntu 12.04 LTS.
When i type

> make install

The following error occur:

> Makefile:111: *** Linux kernel source not configured - missing
>   version.h.  Stop.

in the README file thy say:

> When trying to compile the driver by running make install, the
>   following error may occur:
>
> ```
> "Linux kernel source not configured - missing version.h"
> ```
>
> To solve this issue, create the version.h file by going to the Linux
>   source tree and entering:
>
> ```
> make include/linux/version.h.
> ```

I try to run this command in the `/usr/src/linux*******` folder but no results

(

```
i have linux-headers-3.8.0-29          linux-headers-3.8.0-32

linux-headers-3.8.0-29-generic  linux-headers-3.8.0-32-generic
```

)

any suggestions to fix the problem?

Comment: Your OS supports your ethernet card already.  What are you trying to do?  Where does this driver come from?

Comment: I'm trying to install the original driver offered with the ethernet card (from the CD) @Peter

Comment: The e1000 is already supported very well by the 12.04 Linux kernel.  You don't need to install the driver from the CD, which is intended for older kernels.

Comment: but @Peter are all options supported by this standard driver? for example i tried to disable the crc checksum to receive all packets (even with errors) but bad packets are not relayed to the upper layers (application layer), that's why i'm trying to install the original driver to use all functionality

Comment: This question is now diverging completely from the original.  I think you need a new question that states what you are trying to do, how you're trying to do it, what exact hardware you have.  Also note in your question that you're not sure if the vendor-provided driver will help, and provide a link to an online location for this driver if possible.  Right now there's just not enough information to even start.  I would be very surprised if the built-in Intel e1000 driver were not completely functional.

Comment: NO the OS *does not* support this already, it breaks every so often with a new kernel. Please try and address the issue, and not the reasons. This is a very common problem..

Answer (score 0):

Some people just like to compile. Searching this error pointed me here.

As it turns out the compiler is looking at the wrong kernel version, and the headers for this are not installed on the OS.

Best solved editing the specfile.

Answer (score 0):

Install build-essential using terminal or synaptic.
Restart computer, it will work.
Thank you.